# How to create Calculated Field Filters in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am making a web analytics dashboard with Google Data Studio and I would like to show the conversion rate funnel; to find this, I have to divide the number of `Unique Pageviews` from the bottom of the funnel vs the number of `Unique Pageviews` at the top of the funnel; for example:

```
Page= www.test.com/page-funnel-1 -> 100
      Filter: Page = */page-funnel-1
Page= www.test.com/page-funnel-end -> 10
      Filter: Page = */page-funnel-end
CR: 10/100 = 10%
```

My problem is that in Google Data Studio I cannot use graphic fields to make calculated fields. I have tried to make a calculated field where I apply the necessary filters but Google Data Studio does not allow me to mix metrics with dimensions:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page, ".*home-type") THEN Unique Page View
  ELSE 0
END
```

**This field is the one you would need to calculate in Google Data Studio**:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way that it can be achieved is by using [Ratio Metrics](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9457859):

1. Select the `/page-funnel-end` [Scorecard](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479);
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Select the `/page-funnel-1` [Scorecard](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479) (so that both Scorecards are selected);
3. ***Blend Data***: Right click on one of the selected [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479) and click on `Blend data` from the Drop-down to create a new [Scorecard](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479), a [Ratio Metric](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9457859).

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/bf78a45b-3212-4c42-bc48-f301a078cb1e) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]